# Changing the TextView in included layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-include

I am trying to change the text in TextView during the program execution to the data sent from a different activity.

The TextView `id="@+id/userName"` is in my  *nav_header_main*  layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/navigation_view">

<ImageView android:layout_width="83dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@mipmap/user" android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_weight="0.84" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello" android:id="@+id/userDetail" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and it is included in *main.xml* as

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"     app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

I tried to set the text by *OnCreate* method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
NavigationView nav_view= (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
userName = (TextView) nav_view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
String user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("User");
userName.setText(user); //user is a string
```

but still I am getting the "Null Pointer Error" during execution. Did I miss something to get things working correctly?

Comment: *main.xml* is the xml file of the activity in which you're trying to change the TextView?

Comment: no, its in nav_header_main.xml, .. i should add that in the question...

Comment: Post your *nav_header_main.xml* and the *onCreate()* method of the activity in which you're trying to set the text.

Comment: @Rami files uploaded as u asked for

Comment: can you post your onCreate perhaps like fully

Comment: @JordanSeanor updated

Comment: @SaugatSingh can you actually add your logcat output as well? It may not even be attributed to the TextView and may be associated with your intent.

Comment: No the logcat showed the error at line in the `userName.setText(user);` _OnCreate_ method, I have *Log* the intent and its working fine. Omitting the code also works without error

Comment: @SaugatSingh check if you *(user != null )*.

Comment: @Rami    
`Log.v("Intent recieved: ", user);` shows data

Comment: @SaugatSingh Try to remove *nav_view*  from *nav_view.findViewById(R.id.userName);*

Comment: @Rami still the same error. feeling frustuated, please see if the way I have coded has some error?

Comment: @SaugatSingh Give a try with: `View header = nav_view.getHeaderView(0);` to get the header layout then  `userName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userName);`.

Comment: @Rami finally, thank you, saved my day, Perhaps you post your ans so that I could accept.

Comment: @SaugatSingh You're welcome, glad to hep!

Comment: please insert more details for your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future users:

First, you need to get the header view: `View header = nav_view.getHeaderView(0);`

Then get your widgets: `userName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userName);`